# List all HTML files in a directory python code not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, os.walk

I am trying to list all HTML files in a directory using `os.walk`  but it returning none instead of file names

Here is my code

```
def read_dirctory():
    matches = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/home/akallararajappan/www.mangalam.com/agriculture'):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.html'):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
   return matches
```

What is the problem here ?  I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I have 1000 html files in the directory

output:

```
[]
```

Comment: One solution I can readily suggest is that, `return` should be unindented twice...

Comment: Then I am getting an error

Comment: What I meant is that, `return` should not be inside the loops.

Comment: Still it returns none, I have 1000 html files there

Comment: Is using 'glob' out of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. BTW there are a already a [couple of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3964690/930271) like this.

```
def read_directory():
    matches =[]
    directory = '/home/akallararajappan/www.mangalam.com/agriculture'
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.html'):
                matches.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    return matches
```